# reaching array variable inside html

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
export class FirmsPage {
  langs;
  langForm;
  loading: any;
  username : string;
  firms;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public firmService: FirmService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
     this.username = this.navParams.get("param");
     this.langForm = new FormGroup({
      "langs": new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.showLoader();
    this.getFirms();
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }

  getFirms(){
       this.firmService.getFirms()
       .subscribe(
           data => {
             this.firms = data;
           },
           error => alert(error),
           () => console.log("Finished")
       );
    }
```

I am getting firms as json from rest and subscribe them to the firms array. Now I want to use that firms array in my html file like following;

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label>Go</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value='' checked="true"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
```

I want to give a value to that radio button with firms array. I am trying to do it like `value={{firm[0].adi}}`. However it gives me error. So, how can I give value to this radio button?

Comment: firm is not defined. If you meant firms...it's not initialized. It's good to do firms: [] = []. I think.

Comment: @jmachnik when I do that it says "Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[]'."

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care that the expression doesn't throw when `firm` is `null` because the response from the server request hasn't yet arrived:

```
[value]="firms?.length && firms[0]?.adi"
```

`{{}}` might work as well instead of `[]` but `{{}}` does string interpolation, which is often not what you want.

Comment: calling getFirms() inside constructor may can solve it?

Comment: it is complaining about the "firms" array undefined, but I tried to call getFirms() in contructor it is still undefined.

Comment: Perhaps because you named it `firms` instead of `firm`? ;-)